# How to paint Java step gradient method

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, gradient

```
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
```

Normally Java paint gradient smoothly.

Can Java paint step gradient in GUI?

Comment: You can do so programmatically, for instance using [linear interpolation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532/generating-gradients-programmatically) in which the interpolation between the endpoints falls into bins rather than being continuous.

Comment: See also [`LinearGradientPaint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/LinearGradientPaint.html).