# Animate the text sequence gradually from one color to another

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

Im a fresher to android..and now i need to animate a text sequence given below and after one cycle the text color should change from red to white gradually.

A

An

And

Andr

Andro

Androi

Android

Comment: How is it presented in Android? Is it a TextView?

Comment: yes,using textview.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using a TextView, you can use a loop to gradually change the color and append the text dynamically e.g.

```
char[] letters = "Android".toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  view.append(letters[i]);
  view.setTextColor(color);
}
```

A helpful link on creating the gradient is here 
[Generating gradients programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532/generating-gradients-programmatically)
and to use that to create a color, you can use

```
view.setTextColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));
```

Comment: Thank you....I understood the code but can I  get something other than view....because Im not having much idea using view.

Comment: The view can be your TextView.

Comment: @Dinsha view in this case your text view. `TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);`

Comment: I have done using two TextViews overlapping.....in TextView1 I have assigned the text and color in xml file...and in TextView2 I need to assign a text and color programmatically with the above sequence model..but this cncept doesnt work as my idea.