# How to invoke a helper method with arguments in EL

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, el

I have a list of values in a managed bean.

```
Values

120
70
30
60
```

However the requirement is to map these values to a Color in between red(0%
) and green(100%). I need to provide this converted color value to a column of a data driven component(similar to a `h:dataTable`) that has a *color* attribute which can be an EL(Expression Language) expression.

So for percentage to color conversion I can use the simple algorithm given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25024/1527084) . Although it is in JavaScript it can easily be written in Java. Lets call this method `color()` and let it be declared in the managed bean that has the original List(values).

```
 Color  color(double percentage){}
```

Now my problem is that how to first pass the percentages to this method  and then pass the  converted Color value back to the component during runtime.

For example

```
<nameSpace:dataTable  values="#{bean.Values} var="row" ...>
   <nameSpace:column  color="#{expression language syntax}" -->
```

So this expreesion language should be able to:

1. First compute the percentage (so for the value 30 , the percentage should be (( 30 /120 ) * 100)= 25 and then pass this percentage to `color()` function.
2. And then go on to pass the percentage to previously declared `color()` method and then set the return of that method to the `color` attrbute.

I am using JSF2.0. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Maybe you want to [create a custom EL function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function)?

Comment: Can't you apply the `color` algorithm to process the given values in your list before returning them through your `getValues` bean method? IMHO you shouldn't leave that kind of pre-processing to an EL function but to the bean, who could instead return a ready-to-use list, if possible.

Comment: JSP is deprecated in JSF2 and succeeded by Facelets. To confirm, are you *really* using JSP or is this a careless mixup of "JSP/EL" as "one and same thing"? In case you're really using JSP, you need a different way for registering a custom EL function than as proposed in the answer to the question in elias' comment. Another option would be to utilize the new EL 2.2 feature of invoking methods with arguments. But for that we'd need to know the target container's make/version.

Comment: @BalusC I am indeed using Facelets. Sorry for the confusion. I have removed JSP  the tag.And the target container is WebLogic Server 12c (12.1.1)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways.

1. [Create a custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function).

   ```
   <nameSpace:column color="#{f:color(row.percentage)}">
   ```
2. [Utilize EL 2.2 feature of invoking methods with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273729/how-to-call-a-method-with-a-parameter-in-jsf/5273864#5273864) (Weblogic 12c is Servlet 3.0 compatible, so this should work provided that webapp-supplied `web.xml` is also Servlet 3.0 compatible).

   ```
   <nameSpace:column color="#{bean.color(row.percentage)}">
   ```
3. Prepare the desired data directly in the model.

   ```
   <nameSpace:column color="#{row.color}">
   ```
4. Programmatically evaluate EL expression `#{row}` in the getter method.

   ```
   <nameSpace:column color="#{bean.color}">
   ```

   with

   ```
   Double percentage = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{row.percentage}", Double.class);
   // ...
   ```

Comment: your first second and fourth answers all say `row.percentage`. Actually I don't have percentages directly . They needs to be calculated as I mentioned in my question. Option 3 is the easiest but unfortunately I have no control over the datamodel.

Comment: Just substitute it with the value(s) which needs to be used as basis for calculation. Your question didn't state the concrete functional requirement clearly, so I'd just have to "stub" something to make the solutions fundamentally clear.

Comment: what you meant by "that webapp-supplied web.xml is also Servlet 3.0 compatible" ?

Comment: Click the link at point 2. So.. Just a Servlet 3.0 compatible root declaration (with `version="3.0"`, etc) and not e.g. Servlet 2.5 or 2.4 or even 2.3 with DTD.

Comment: I am not sure how to go about calculating the percentage that my `color()` method would need without knowing the maximum value. Any ideas?

Comment: I have no idea what you're concretely asking there. That look like just an algorithm question for which you apparently already have an example in JavaScript flavor. If not, please be more clear in stating the concrete functional requirement.