# How to add multi colored percentage bar that changes colors according to its progress?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Jquery that i use to get the progress and add the percentage!

```
/* getting the percentage of the multi step verification */

$('.track').change(function(e) {
    update_percentage();
});
// supports any number of inputs and calculates done as %
function update_percentage() {
    var count = $('.track').length;
    var length = $('.track').filter(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).length;
    var done = Math.floor(length * (100 / count));
    $('.perc').text(done);

    $('.meter').width(done + "%");

        $(document).ready(function(){
        $a = done;
        $("#applicant_percentages").val($a);
    });
}
```

This is where the progress meter is shown in a bar as well as in percentage

```
<div class="progress-meter">
        <h5>Profile Strength <span class='perc'>0</span>%</h5>
        <span class="meter"></span>
        <br>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.meter {
 display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color:green;
}
```

[image: Sample]

I am getting the percentage of the number of input that are filled in a form! i have put the value i take into a progress bar .. but now what need the to change the colors of the progress bar once they reach certain values.

And sorry if i am unclear!

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007/conditional-formatting-percentage-to-color-conversion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional formatting -- percentage to color conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007/conditional-formatting-percentage-to-color-conversion)

Comment: @AbhishekPandey - what purpose does suggesting the same link someone else has serve?

Comment: can you just show what exactly you want with a rough image

Comment: sorry for being unclear .. i have added an image above to make things clear!

Comment: @enhzflep FYI I have marked it as a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an array containing your required bands

```
let colors = [
    {max:20,color:'red'}, 
    {max:75,color:'yellow'},
    {max:100,color:'green'}];
```

You can find the right colour using `Array.find` based on the `done` amount:

```
var color = colors.find(x => x.max >= done).color;
```

And apply this to your progress bar using jQuery `css`

```
$('.meter').width(done + "%").css('background-color',color);
```

Live example below:

```js
/* getting the percentage of the multi step verification */

$('.track').change(function(e) {
    update_percentage();
});

let colors = [{max:20,color:'red'}, {max:75,color:'yellow'},{max:100,color:'green'}];


// supports any number of inputs and calculates done as %
function update_percentage() {
    var count = $('.track').length;
    var length = $('.track').filter(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).length;
    
    var done = Math.floor(length * (100.0 / count));
    var color = colors.find(x => x.max >= done).color;
    
    $('.perc').text(done);

    $('.meter').width(done + "%").css('background-color',color);
}
```

```css
.meter {
 display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="track" type="text">
<input class="track" type="text">
<input class="track" type="text">
<input class="track" type="text">
<input class="track" type="text">
<input class="track" type="text">

<div class="progress-meter">
    <h5>Profile Strength <span class='perc'>0</span>%</h5>
    <span class="meter"></span>
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you exactly what i wanted! thank you to others also who tried to help me!